# Unity Colliders - How do I detect nearby objects without my detection ranges detecting each other

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection

How can I get both colliders' types in a trigger overlap message like `OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)`?

Example:

- `objects A and B` both have a `BoxCollider2D` and `CircleCollider2D` components.
- Then, `object A` enters one of the trigger colliders of `object B`.
- I can get `object B`'s collider type with the `is` operator.

How can I get A's collider type?

The reason I want this is that I want only collisions where `object A`'s `CircleCollider2D` touches `object B`'s `BoxCollider2D`.

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other is BoxCollider2D)
        //Do Code
}
```

Here is a table of what I want: I want only to register trigger overlaps from `CircleCollider2D to BoxCollider2D`. With the `is` operator, I can safely remove all collisions to `CircleCollider2D` but collisions between two `BoxCollider2D` stay, which I do not want.

```
+------------------+---------------+------------------+
|  Row to Column   | BoxCollider2D | CircleCollider2D | 
+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| BoxCollider2D    | No            | No               | 
| CircleCollider2D | Yes           | No               | 
+------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

**Edit**
The real questions was to detect nearby objects without the detection range dectecting each other.

Comment: Have you considered using physics layers to prevent the unwanted collider pairs from interacting in the first place?

Comment: Yes, at the moment, I'm already in another physics layer. What I am trying to do is to know what objects are in a certain range of my object. I have a circle collider for the range and a box collider of the shape of the object.

Comment: Sounds like you want a Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc, not a CircleCollider2D

Comment: oh, lol that does exactly what i need. Thanks a lot (if you want to put it as answer, I will upvote)

Comment: I recommend editing your question to ask the question you're really trying to answer ("how do I detect nearby objects without my detection ranges detecting each other") then write your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Physics2D.OverlapCircleNonAlloc`, you can set an area around a point (my gameobject) and then saving the results in a `Collider2D[]` array which contains all objects nearby from the range I want.